Emacs: How do I disable "deprecated" warnings
Lately, I started to see ". . . deprecated" warnings at startup.
How do I disable only this type of warning?
As I understand, they come from third-party packages I load from within .emacs.d/init.el. Because these warnings are for the authors of the packages, they aren't useful to me.
There is a past Q&A that discusses how to disable all warnings in general:
How do I disable warnings at initialization in Emacs?
But I don't want to do that, not to miss my own mistakes in my init.el.
Edit: Here is an example of the warning messages I see:
⛔ Warning (emacs): ‘:events-buffer-scrollback-size’ deprecated. Use ‘events-buffer-config’.

But, these messages change from time to time. My guess is this: The emacs developers decide that some functions and variables are deprecated and switch on the warning.  These warnings are signals to the package developers in order to encourage them to replace the deprecated functions or variables.
But the warnings aren't useful to mere users. These warnings started many months ago. Initially I expected that the package developers would quickly fix their codes and the warnings would go away soon.  But that's not been the case.
So, it would be nice if you can disable only those warnings which result from the use of deprecated functions or variables, or if there is a "debug mode" switch or something like that, in such a way that the "deprecated" warnings are visible only in the debug mode.


This question is similar to: How do I disable warnings at initialization in Emacs?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@nega I already quoted the Q&A thread you point out and stated the reason why that's not the solution to my problem. This time, I've edited my question extensively to make it even clearer.

They're warnings, not errors. Does it really matter right now? If they're from packages submit a bug report and help make things better for everyone.

@nega I'm not sure what you want to achieve by that question of yours. How should I modify the question I wrote above?  The warnings bother me, which is the reason I ask the question.  I'm sure the OP of the other thread you quote posted the question because s/he was bothered. . .  I guess this answers your question "Does it really matter?"  Yes, it does, to the extent that the warnings bother you.  I agree with you that I should submit a bug report to each package.

Generally warnings "percolate up" from a common "method". It is difficult for anyone to provide suggestions with your lack of context and details. Maybe you could provide the actual warning messages.

use emacs -Q and provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

"It is difficult for anyone to provide suggestions with your lack of context and details."  I see what you mean. I'll provide an example soon.  But, the problem is many different packages give this type of warnings and the warnings change as you keep upgrading packages. So, my problem is not about a particular package.  It's been a problem for many months. I guess the root cause is that emacs developers have decided to issue warnings on some obsolete functions and variables. You remember that when cl functions became obsolete, similar warnings flooded users?

add  '(emacs) to warning-suppress-types or warning-suppress-log-types, eg.  (add-to-list 'warning-suppress-types '(emacs))

@Rorschach Thank you!! That seems to be exactly what I've been looking for. So, "warning" has subtypes, right?  And what you say amounts to suppressing only the warning subtype emacs, which I guess means warning coming from the core emacs.  Is that right?  In any case, your suggestion seems to be working.

yea, they have subtypes. For example, to suppress a subtype (let ((warning-suppress-types '((my-type sub-1)))) (lwarn '(my-type sub-1) :warning "oops")). That wont suppress warnings like (my-type sub-2).

[This answer is credited to @Rorschach . See her/his comments to the original post. I just copy her/his words here to complete this Q&A thread.]
To suppress this type of warnings only, add '(emacs) to warning-suppress-types or warning-suppress-log-types to your init.el. For example,
(add-to-list 'warning-suppress-types '(emacs))

I confirm that this has suppressed the warning popup windows I've been seeing.
It seems that emacs warning has subtypes. I've tried to locate documentation that describes the existing subtypes but failed so far.
